# Is it just me...or is "Facebook Mobile Web" only for PHP?

Tags: php, python, django, facebook, mobile

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Mobile

I use Django/Python as my mobile website.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library may be "officially' for PHP, **But** that doesnt stop you from making your own.

I would suggest looking at the API. You may be able to port the calls to python using python's `httplib`.

All the PHP library does is make curl POST and GET calls to Facebook's REST server. 
If you are familiar with PHP or Javascript you may be able to look at the library and port the methods yourself.

I suggest a quick google search starting with: [python facebook api](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python+facebook+api&aq=1&aqi=g10&oq=python+face)

edit: In fact I just found: [pyfacebook](http://code.google.com/p/pyfacebook/) or [pyfacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) (on github) These might be a good starting point for you also.

If I wasnt behind a restrictive work firewall I would pull up some API examples. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"Facebook Connect for Mobile Web is a PHP library..."